# Protractor does not load the page correctly

Tags: protractor

After clicking on the confirmation button, the next screen should display a confirmation message. But protractor just loads the page without display this confirmation. The strange thing is that I have the same code for other pages, and in all of them, Protractor works fine. It is an Angular website, as you can see on the screenshot

[image]

This is my conf file

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html'
});


// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  getPageTimeout : 12000000,

  capabilities: {
    "browserName": 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {

        mobileEmulation: {
            "device": 'Zebra TC20',
            "deviceMetrics": {
                "width": 340,
                "height": 440,
                "pixelRatio": 3.0
            }
        }
    }
},
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true,

   // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
   framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: ['../tests/ReturnToVendor.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 150000
  },

  // Setup the report before any tests start
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },

  // Assign the test reporter to each running instance
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  },

  // Close the report after all tests finish
  afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  },

  onPrepare: function () {

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      savePath: './',
      filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));
    var fs = require('fs-extra');

    fs.emptyDir('screenshots/', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
            specDone: function(result) {
                if (result.status == 'failed') {
                    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                            var stream = fs.createWriteStream('screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName+ '.png');
                            stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                            stream.end();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }));
  },

  //HTMLReport called once tests are finished
onComplete: function() {
  var browserName, browserVersion;
  var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

  capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
     browserName = caps.get('browserName');
     browserVersion = caps.get('version');
     platform = caps.get('platform');

     var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');

     testConfig = {
         reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
         outputPath: './',
         outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
         screenshotPath: './screenshots',
         testBrowser: browserName,
         browserVersion: browserVersion,
         modifiedSuiteName: false,
         screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
         testPlatform: platform
     };
     new HTMLReport().from('xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
 });
}


};
```

This is my spec

```
 it('should click on checkmark', async function () {
        await element(by.css(".ng-star-inserted > .mat-button-wrapper > .mat-icon")).click(); ////click on the checkmark
        browser.sleep(2000);

        element(by.css('button.mat-primary > .mat-button-wrapper')).click(); /////////Click on confirm
        browser.sleep(2000);

////////Here I would like to see the confirmation message       

             element(by.css("h3")).getText().then(function(text){
                 console.log(text);
                 expect(text).toBe("Submission Success")
             })
```

Any help is really appreciate

Comment: You have to add await for everything , everything in protractor is a promise, so browser is a promise and you have add await browser.sleep

Answer (score 1):

In protractor you should use inbuild control flow or use await. You cannot use both.

Remove async from spec and remove all awaits or disable control flow and add await to all browser instance.

To disable controlflow add  :

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
```

To config:

**Config file:**

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  getPageTimeout : 12000000,


  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    "browserName": 'chrome',       
},

SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    onPrepare: function(){
       browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
     },

   framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['../tests/ReturnToVendor.js'],    

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 150000
  },
```

**And your spec:**

```
 it('should click on checkmark', async function () {
            await element(by.css(".ng-star-inserted > .mat-button-wrapper > .mat-icon")).click(); ////click on the checkmark
            await browser.sleep(2000);

            await element(by.css('button.mat-primary > .mat-button-wrapper')).click(); /////////Click on confirm
            await browser.sleep(2000);

            ////////Here I would like to see the confirmation message       

            let text = await element(by.css("h3")).getText();

            console.log(text);
            expect(text).toBe("Submission Success")
```

Comment: I did as you suggested: I disabled the control flow and addeawait to all browser instance. But then I got: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details".

Comment: So you are testing a non angular page

Comment: so you can use browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); in on prepare. Else protractor wil lcheck for angular in you page

Comment: I updated the config file see now

Comment: it is an Angular website, I attached the picture. This same code works fine on other pages.

Comment: @IngriddBrito set it to first false and  then if it doesn't work try true . See whats happening

Comment: set it to false and to to true I gtt: An error was thrown in an afterAll, but on my conf file I dont have after all.

Comment: @IngriddBrito you have after all in any other spec ?

Comment: no, all the specs don't have after all. Plus, in all of them have this snippet. But just on this spec Protractor presents this problem.

Comment: @IngriddBrito what's the error in after all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107985/discussion-between-ingridd-brito-and-pdhide).